# Booting to blank screen eOS 5.1

Tags: boot, nvidia, kernel, battery, nvidia-driver

When booting up my laptop from power off or hibernated state I am booted into a black screen with a small white under-score in the top left.
Nothing proceeds to happen.

To work around this I power down and boot to grub, then load the previous kernel.
Does anyone know how to remove the latest kernel, or to block it from booting? How to disable kernel updates until a stable one is released?

I have also tried to install Nvidia drivers, which I've seen mentioned as problem software. Is this the case?
The last possible cause of my boot woes is battery management software. Does anyone know of anything that works and is stable?

Thanks in advance!

Laptop specs:
Quad-Core Intel® Core™ i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] (rev a1)
16GB memory